Comment exprimer la « grazing table » ?

Manger sans se presser, en grignotant ici et là, c’est ce que font les
invités autour d’une « grazing table ». (Source)


[Un élément d'une telle « grazing table », (Source)]
L'analogie avec le broutage et le pâturage m'inspire peu. L'article suggère « plateaux de fromages et de charcuteries », « table de dégustation » ou de « table de grignotage ». Voir aussi par ex. ceci.
Comment préfère-t-on exprimer l'idée, a-t-on besoin de nommer ça sous forme d'un type de « table » (réussit-on à exprimer autre chose que la destination ?) et sinon comment, une référence au « plateau » suffit-elle (et si on a la dinde ensuite ?) ; et pourquoi ?

En somme c'est un buffet, dressé de façon particulièrement artistique, mais ça reste un buffet.

p.s. @Gilles 'SO nous est hostile', toi as-tu une idée ?

Je dirais tout simplement un buffet, qui me semble le terme consacré (aussi pour traduire potluck, entre autres), sans rentrer dans les détails de la présentation dudit buffet, sur une planche en particulier ou autrement. Ceci traduirait plutôt l'idée du "repas" que l'objet même.
Pour l'objet de la photo, on peut dire plateau, en parallèle avec le plateau de fromage qui circule à la fin des repas avant le dessert. "On fera juste un plateau". Ou bien "planche", encore plus concret. Avec le contexte, on comprendra que c'est la planche sur laquelle sont disposés les mets. Aussi, planche apéro, trouvé ici (merci @jlliagre).

Dans une autre direction, on voit parfois éventail, assortiment, palette pour mettre l'accent sur la diversité des mets servis. "Un buffet permettra aux invités de déguster un éventail de fromages et charcuteries...". A noter aussi, on utilise assez facilement le terme sucré-salé (si c'est le cas).
Dans le même ordre d'idées pour un repas léger où les invités se servent eux-mêmes sans que la table soit dressée, on a collation et peut-être même apéritif. "Une collation légère sous la forme d'un buffet", par exemple. Ou bien "un buffet-apéritif permettra aux invités de déguster une sélection de fromages et de charcuteries..." - mais on s'éloigne sans doute si on veut simplement trouver un terme pour la "table" de l'image dans la question (apéritif est couramment abrégé en "apéro" en langue familière).

plateau de fromages et de fruits https://www.mamatraiteur.fr/products/plateau-de-fromages-et-de-fruits-1kg Par contre, buffet, non.


Planche de dégustation de fin d'année.



On ne peut pas déguster si ce n'est pas la fin de l'année? ;-)

@Frank Pas question ! La période est imposée :-)

Planche à partager.
On pourrait mettre "Planche à partager" comme légende de la photo (support + nourriture à picorer). (Graffito, 2)

Je ne vois pas pourquoi ne pas garder le mot table qui, dans le terme anglais grazing table, désigne bien le support sur lequel se trouve un assortiment de planches où sont disposés divers mets prêts à être mangés par les convives rassemblés autour de ladite table. Si l'expression « table de dégustation » proposé par l'article lié dans la question ne plait pas, ni celui de « table de grignotage », le grignotage ayant une valeur négative de nos jours¹, et que celui de « broutage » parait peu inspirant, peut-être à cause de l'image des bovins qu'elle évoque, pourquoi ne pas faire allusion à un animal connoté de façon plus poétique : l'oiseau. Ce dernier picore². On aurait ainsi une « table de picorage » ou une « table de mets à picorer » si le suffixe age parait un peu lourd à certains. Si on veut introduire une allusion aux arts plastiques, on peut introduire le terme d'éléments qui fait partie du champ lexical des arts visuels : « table d'éléments à picorer ». Et pourquoi ne pas aller jusqu'au « tableau à picorer ». Tel un puzzle à l'envers, le tableau se désagrège au fil de la séance, c'est le happening dans lequel on est à la fois acteur et spectateur.

¹ « Pour votre santé, évitez de grignoter entre les repas » est l'un des trois slogans pouvant accompagner les messages publicitaires ou promotionnels en faveur de certains aliments et boissons. (Arrêté du 27 février 2007 paru au J.O du 28 février 2007)
² Nourriture à picorer ayant déjà été suggéré dans un commentaire de @Graffito. 

Étal (Table où l'on expose les marchandises dans les marchés publics. Le Robert) d'aliments (pour le commun des mortels, d'éléments pour les bobos) à picorer.

Bel étal de délices à picorer.

Plateaux de fromages et de charcuteries.
Table de dégustation.
Table de grignotage.
[ Suggestions dans la source ]

Plateau sucré-salé. (jlliagre)

Même si buffet est utile, ils ont le terme en anglais aussi et ils n'ont pas nommé ça grazing buffet, encore moins juste buffet, donc je pense qu'il y a lieu d'aller plus loin. Justement, la présentation joue un grand rôle ici à mon avis, et donc je me propose d'utiliser ce mot-là et de détourner un peu le sens de bouchées avec présentation de bouchées gourmandes, qui fait qu'on n'a pas à parler de la table ou de la planche/du plateau sur lesquels on peut la trouver. La référence à gourmand/gourmet permettrait d'élever le cadre du simple buffet. On pourrait penser aussi à assortiment ; voire même à tableau en s'appuyant doublement sur le sens du support et de la représentation : tableau de bouchées gourmandes.

En France une bouchée implique certes un met qu'on ne mange que d'une seule bouchée, mais dont la préparation est élaborée à partir d'au moins deux ingrédients. Ça peut être cuit ou cru mais on y trouvera pas des tranches de pain seules, des morceaux de fromage ou de viande isolées, etc...


plateau de fromages et de fruits
Mama Traiteur

plateau de fromages, charcuterie et légumes à croquer florette
florette.fr

plateau de fromages et de charcuteries
fromandises.fr

plateau de fromage et de charcuterie
La Fromagerie d'Auriol
trouvés dans les sites français

Le plateau (qu'on appellera de nos jours plutôt planche, surtout s'ils sont en bois, mais ce n'est pas le but de mon propos) n'est qu'un des éléments de la grazing table. Personnellement j'ai compris que la question potait sur grazing table et pas sur les éléments qui la composent, voir la légende que le PO a donnée à sa photo.

@None Je n'ai pas le droit de dire quoique ce soit. Tout est critiqué et de plus en plus. Cela dit, la question porte sur grazing table mais ici la beauté du français est qu'un terme suffit pour rendre le tout si on ajoute de fruits, légumes, charcuterie, etc. qui sont les objets dudit grazing, alors qu'en anglais il faut davantage de mots.
